# How to map classical data onto a Hamiltonian

Tags: qiskit

training for the Hamiltonian. And our general QNN neural network training starts from the classical data set. The general method is to program the classical data into a quantum state, so what if I want to use VQA to train the classical data set? How can a classical data set be transformed into a Hamiltonian instead of a quantum state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of resources you can find online, you can figure it out with these example and tutorials if you know the basics. (qiskit, QGSS 2021, documentation, etc):

1. https://qiskit.org/documentation/machine-learning/tutorials/03_quantum_kernel.html
2. https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLOFEBzvs-VvqJwybFxkTiDzhf5E11p8BI
3. https://pennylane.ai/qml/demos_qml.html

Comment: I've watched all the qiskit quantum machine learning summer videos, but am confused about the construction of the Hamiltonian. There seems to be no plausible explanation, maybe the answer can only be found by reading the paper, which is too difficult for me

Comment: @R-XZhao This lecture 5.2 from QGSS 2021 will help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YpLzSQPrgSc